# Difference between 到处 and 处处

Tags: meaning, usage, difference, word

Apparently 到处 and 处处 means everywhere in English. May I know if both words can be used interchangeably or there are some differences in usage?

Comment: web search yields many answers: https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%A4%84%E5%A4%84%E5%92%8C%E5%88%B0%E5%A4%84%E6%9C%89%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E4%B8%8D%E5%90%8C&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab

Answer (score 5):

From Dictionary:

> **everywhere**:
>
> (adverb): in or to all places.
>
> *e.g. "I've looked everywhere"*
>
> (noun): all places or directions.
>
> *e.g. "everywhere was in darkness"*

~

> When 到处 and 处处 are used as a **noun**, they are interchangeable

Example:

到处都有特价 = 处处都有特价 = everywhere has discount

到处都有人 = 处处都有人 = everywhere has people

到处都有老鼠 = 处处都有老鼠 = everywhere has mice

*'到处' and '处处' here are **nouns** with the same meaning*

> When it is used as an **adverb**, 到處 and 處處 have different meanings.

- 到处 = everywhere; in all place (adv)
- 处处 = in all aspect; in all directions; in all angles (adv)

Example:

到处查询 (ask everywhere) *You go place to place and ask people there*

处处查询 (ask in all aspects) *You inquire all aspect of the object, e.g. Where you live? Where you work? What school you went to?*

到处受阻挠 (be obstructed everywhere) *e.g. Everywhere you go, you are obstructed*

处处受阻挠 (be obstructed in all aspects) *e.g. You want to see the boss and they say no. You try to check the bill and they refuse. You apply to transfer and it is denied*

到处挑剔别人 (pick on people everywhere) *e.g. you go place to place to pick on people*

处处挑剔别人 (pick on people in all aspects) *e.g. you complain about the coffee shop staffs work too slow. You point out someone has bad teeth. You told someone the reason of he being poor is because of his laziness*

*'到处' and '处处' here are **adverbs** with different meanings*

Answer (score 1):

2 more answers: **＂汉语同义词词典＂**  **处处／到处［同］** 副词。表示说话人所指的动作或状态涉及的全部范围。在就场所而言，表示每个地方时可通用。例（１）船上却处处是公共的地方，船面栏边，人人可以来到。（冰心＜寄小读者＞）（２）楼台处处飞春雨，十里人家尽种花。（刘白羽＜春到零丁洋＞）（３）城里到处火光烛天，枪炮齐响。（老舍＜小小的花朵＞）（４）那时，地上地下，到处万马奔腾。（丁宁＜心中的画＞）

**［异］** **［处处］** 还表示＂各个方面＂。可以与＂时时＂并用。例：（１）他在我们面前，时时谈到他的老师，并处处以老师为榜样：＂我的老师就是这样。。。＂（丁宁＜心中的画＞）（２）他的病历记录着他一年的忧患劳累，使她三分之一世纪以来处处＂甘拜下风＂，事事都顺着他，护着他，讨好他。（孟紫＜寿礼＞）（３）他时时处处以共产党员标准来要求自己。

**［到处］** 还表示各个地方。例：（１）我以为要认真的生活。而不是瞪着眼睛，拿着笔记本到处寻摸你的小说。（肖复兴＜生活的感受力＞）（２）他对生命还是充满信心，手术后不久，就下地到处走，。。。（丁宁＜心中的画＞）

**＂对外汉语常用词语对比例释＂**＜副词＞都可以指出全部范围。**（一）意义上** ＂处处＂、＂到处＂都可以表示各个地方。＂处处＂更加强调所有的地方无一例外；＂到处＂表示所有的地方都包括在内，所以多与表示范围的＂都＂配合使用。例如：这里处处是春天。祖国处处有亲人。草原上，牛群、羊群、马群处处可见。车站内外到处都是人。春天，公园里到处飘着花香。浑身上下到处都是土。
**（二）用法上**  **１。**＂处处＂、＂到处＂在句中主要做状语，不能作宾语、定于。例如：植物园里，处处是鲜花，美丽极了！参与竞选活动的人处处可见。现在人的确太多了，到街上一看，到处都是人。今天是＂六一＂儿童节，公园里到处是孩子们兴致勃勃的笑脸。＊这里很美，我要去处处／到处看看。＊在法国时，他游遍了法国的处处／到处。＊今天不知怎么了，处处／到处的商店都不开门。**２。**＂处处＂还可以表示各个方面的意思，在句中作状语。＂到处＂没有这一意义和用法。例如：队长时时处处严格要求自己。他处处为别人着想。他总是处处走在前面。＊：队长时时到处严格要求自己。＊他到处为别人着想。＊他总是到处走在前面。

Comment: In the sentence 在法国时，他游遍了法国的处处／到处, is 處處/到處a 狀語？Frankly, I find the usage of 處處/到處 here unusual. I'd rather use 各處. 他总是到处走在前面?? I'm not sure what this means.

Answer (score 1):

到处 used in most informal occasion

处处 is in opposite，in most formal occasion